# How to handle multiple iterator types

Tags: c++, data-structures, stl, iterator

I have a custom datastructure, which can be accessed in multiple ways. I want to try to keep this datastructure to keep to STL-standards as well as possible. So I already have lot's of typedefs, which give template parameters the STL-names. This is business as usual for me by now.

However I am not so sure how to correctly add iterators to my datastructure. The main problem I am facing is, that there would be multiple iteration policies over the datastructure. The easiest use case is iterating over all elements, which would be handled well by STL-Conforming iterators over the datastructure. However one might also want to access elements, which are somehow similar to a given key. I would also like to iterate over all these similar elements in a way which I can interface with the STL.

These are the ideas I have thought about so far:

- **Provide only one type of iterator**:

This is basicly what `std::map` does. The start and end iterators for a subrange are provided by `std::map::lower_bound()` and `std::map::upper_bound()`.

However this works well, because the iterators returned by `begin()`, `end()`, `lower_bound()` and `upper_bound()` are compatible, i.e. the `operator==()` can be given a very well defined meaning on these. In my case this would be hard to get right, or might even be impossible to give some clear semantics. For example I probably would get some cases where `it1==it2` but `++it1!=++it2`. I am not sure if this is allowed by the STL.

- **Provide multiple types of iterators**:

Much easier to provide clean `operator==()` semantics. Nasty on the other hand because it enlarges the number of types.

- **Provide one type of iterator and use stl::algorithms for specialized access**

I am not sure if this is possible at all. The iteration state should be kept by the iterator somehow (either directly or in a Memento). Using this approach would mean to specialize all stl::algorithms and access the predicate directly in the specialization. Most likely impossible, and if possible a very bad idea.

Right now I am mostly opting for Version 1, i.e. to provide only one type of iterator at all. However since I am not clear on how to clean up the semantics, I have not yet decided.

How would you handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard containers support two iteration policies with two iterator types: `::iterator` and `::reverse_iterator`. You can convert between the two using the constructor of `std::reverse_iterator`, and its member function `base()`.

Depending how similar your iteration policies are, it may or may not be easy to provide conversions to different iterator types. The idea is that the result should point at the "equivalent position" in the iteration policy of the destination type. For reverse iterators, this equivalence is defined by saying that if you insert at that point, the result is the same. So if `rit` is a reverse iterator, `vec.insert(rit.base(), ...)` inserts an element "before" `rit` *in the reverse iteration*, that is to say *after* the element pointed to by `rit` in the container. This is quite fiddly, and will only get worse when the iteration policies are completely unrelated. But if all of your iterator types are (or can be made to look like) wrappers around the "normal" iterator that goes over all elements, then you can define conversions in terms of that underlying iterator position.

You only actually *need* conversions if there are member functions that add or remove elements of the container, because you probably don't want to have to provide a separate overload for each iterator type (just like standard containers don't define `insert` and `erase` for reverse iterators). If iterators are used solely to point at elements, then most likely you can do without them.

If the different iteration policies are all iterating in the normal order over a subset of the elements, then look at `boost::filter_iterator`.

> I probably would get some cases where `it1==it2` but `++it1!=++it2`. I am
>   not sure if this is allowed by the STL.

If I understand correctly, you got `it1` by starting at `thing.normal_begin()`, and you got `it2` by starting at `thing.other_policy_begin()`. The standard containers don't define the result of comparing iterators of the same type that belong to different ranges, so if you did use a common type, then I think this would be fine provided the documentation makes it clear that although `operator==` does happen to work, the ranges are separate according to where the iterator came from.

For example, you could have a `skip_iterator` which takes as a constructor parameter the number of steps it should move forward each time `++` is called. Then you could either include that integer in the comparison, so that `thing.skip_begin(1) != thing.skip_begin(2)`, or you could exclude it so that `thing.skip_begin(1) == thing.skip_begin(2)` but `++(++(thing.skip_begin(1))) == ++(thing.skip_begin(2))`. I think either is fine provided it's documented, or you could document that comparing them is UB unless they came from the same starting point.

Answer (score 3):

Why are more types a problem? It does not necessarily mean much more code. For instance, you could make you iterator-type a template that takes an iteration-policy as template-parameter. The iteration-policy could then provide the implementation of the iteration:

```
struct iterate_all_policy {
    iterate_all_policy(iterator<iterate_all_policy> & it) : it(it) {}

    void advance() { /* implement specific advance here */ }
private:
    iterator<iterate_all_policy> & it;
}
```

You will probably have to make the iteration-policy-classes friends of the iterator-types.

Comment: Yes, this was mostly the way I would have done it in this case. The other iterators would basically become a typedef for the template instantiation. Maybe this solution only does not seem so well because none of the STL-Collections go this way (maybe this is just not needed).

Comment: @LiKao: The standard containers do not need such a mechanism, because they do not support different iteration-policies.